# How to copy all revisions from trunk to branch one by one

Tags: svn

I have following repository structure

```
A         repo1\trunk
A         repo1\branches
Adding         repo1\branches
Adding         repo1\trunk
Committed revision 1.

A         repo1\trunk\sources
Adding         repo1\trunk\sources
Committed revision 2.

A         repo1\trunk\sources\file1.txt
Adding         repo1\trunk\sources\file1.txt
Transmitting file data .  
Committed revision 3.

A         repo1\trunk\sources\file2.txt
Adding         repo1\trunk\sources\file2.txt
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 4.
```

Is it possible **to copy** all revisions from trunk to branch one by one?
Something like this:

```
svn copy svn://localhost/repo1/trunk@2 svn://localhost/repo1/branches/b1 -m "m1" 
svn copy svn://localhost/repo1/trunk@3 svn://localhost/repo1/branches/b1 -m "m2" 
svn copy svn://localhost/repo1/trunk@4 svn://localhost/repo1/branches/b1 -m "m3" 
etc
```

Or in this case revisions should be **merged** one by one?
As a result I need to copy all revisions from trunk to branch b1 abd have following structure of branch b1:

```
b1/sources/file1.txt
b1/sources/file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to copy each revision individually. If you are only concerned with having both `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` in the `sources` subdirectory, you only need to create a branch of the latest trunk and be done with it:

```
svn cp svn://localhost/repo1/trunk svn://localhost/repo1/branches/b1 -m 'Create branch'
```

If for some reason - that is not really clear to me - you really need to do it revision by revision, the correct strategy would be to create a branch at a certain revision, e.g.

```
svn cp svn://localhost/repo1/trunk@1 svn://localhost/repo1/branches/b1 -m 'Create branch'
```

and then *merge* all further revisions, e.g. like this

```
svn co svn://localhost/repo1/branches/b1
cd b1
svn merge ^/trunk -c 2
svn ci -m 'Merged revision 2'
svn up
svn merge ^/trunk -c 3
svn ci -m 'Merged revision 3'
svn up
...
```